# Create Meeting with "allow new time proposal" disabled

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook, office-automation

I'm trying to use PowerShell to create a new meeting. We have a requirement to disable the "Allow New Time Proposal" button for this meeting. My script works to create the meeting but I'm unable to find the property on the meeting object.

The option is available in the Outlook UI
[image]

I've reviewed the [Microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem) but I don't see an option disable "Allow New Time Proposal".

Here is my code PowerShell code.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$Meeting = $Outlook.CreateItem($olItemType.olAppointmentItem)
$Meeting.AllDayEvent            = $True
$Meeting.Body                   = "Review DeathStar design for vulnerabilities"
$Meeting.BusyStatus             = 1
$Meeting.DoNotforwardMeeting    = $True
$Meeting.End                    = $End
$Meeting.Location               = "Grand Moff Tarkin meeting hall"
$Meeting.Recipients.Add('Moff.Gideon@ImperialDeptMilitaryResearch.GalaticEmpire.Gov')
$Meeting.ReminderSet            = $False
$Meeting.ResponseRequested      = $false
$Meeting.Start                  = $Start
$Meeting.Subject                = "DeathStar Vulnerability Planning"
```

I'm looking for a solution in either PowerShell or VBA, as long as it doesn't require direct interaction with the Outlook UI.

Comment: You may use open-source utility called [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) which allows exploring Extended MAPI internals, so you may find out what properties are required to be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `AppointmentNotAllowPropose` named MAPI property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/825A000B"`) to true using `AppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`:

```
$Meeting = $Outlook.CreateItem($olItemType.olAppointmentItem)
$Meeting.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/825A000B", $true)
```

If you need to see MAPI properties (and their DASL names) not explicitly exposed by Outlook, take a look at the appointment with [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author, click IMessage button).

Comment: Holy cow. This is exactly what I needed. AND you have a tool that exposes all attribute values launched while looking at the UI... incredible.