# Create Outlook Meeting with AllowNewTimeProposals Disabled

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I cannot find such option in documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem

It is available here in Outlook User Interface, I want to have it disabled.

[image: Outlook Meeting]

My code

```
Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutAppoint = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

With OutAppoint
        .RequiredAttendees = RequiredAtendeesString
        .AllDayEvent = True
        '.Recipients.Add ("")
        .Start = StartDate & " " & StartHour
        .End = EndDate & " " & EndHour
        .AllDayEvent = AllDayEvent
        .Subject = Subject
        .Body = Body
        .BusyStatus = olFree
        .Location = Location
        .Save
        .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
        .ReminderSet = False
        .ResponseRequested = False
        .PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/825A000B", $true)
        .Display
End With
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Meeting with "allow new time proposal" disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73353611/create-meeting-with-allow-new-time-proposal-disabled)

Comment: https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/

Comment: @niton Unfortunately not, maybe I will paste fragments of my code here so it might be easier to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need extreme care with brackets.

```
.propertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/825A000B", True
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$true` instead of `true` in VBA.

Powershell? :-)

Comment: I tried using true instead of $true, and I still cannot run the code.
Compiler says that = is expected

Comment: If you save the appointment, do you see that property in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?

Comment: Also, try to set that property first.

Comment: You might also want to get rid of the `Save` call - no reason to save the appointment if you display it, and the user can dismiss it.